# Where do I specify array syntax in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

So I'm a bit confused on why I need to have [] syntax around my scope and http get. Aren't these items already available?

```
 angular.module('NoteApp').controller('NotesIndexController', function($http, $scope))
```

vs

```
 angular.module('NoteApp').controller('NotesIndexController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){ ... }]);
```

Isn't this legal?

```
 angular.module('Test').controller('TestCtrl', function($scope){ ... });
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a common practice for developers to compress their code down to the smallest size before sending it through the network. This is sometimes called minification. When minifying a file, it is common to rename variables to something smaller. (If you've ever stepped through the *angular.min.js* code, you can see that all the variables are usually one or two letters)

Without using the array syntax, when variable names are changed, Angular has no way of knowing what that variable should have been pointing to. The array syntax helps Angular's dependency injector to deduce which module each varable is referring to.

Here's a great article which explains it well: 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/declaring-angularjs-modules-for-minification

Comment: You can also use https://github.com/mgol/grunt-ng-annotate in your build process, which will add those annotations (array syntax) for you, so you'll keep your non-minified code cleaner.